# Creating sections in swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm writing a swagger spec and I have three separate endpoints. How do I separate them in my documentation? I want to have a clear distinction between example: Users, Posts & Other. So each one would have a CRUD description and displayed in swagger UI it would look like:

```
USERS
// user specs

POST
// post specs

OTHER
// other specs
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use tags to accomplish this.

So, on your "paths" object, you sort all your routes and on each one, you add a "tags": ["{resource}"] where it should be grouped.

For example:

```
"paths": {
    "/users": {
        "get": {
            "tags": ["User"],
            "description": "...",
        },
        "post": {
            "tags": ["User"],
            "description": "...",
        }
    },

    "/posts": {
        "get": {
            "tags": ["Post"],
            "description": "...",
        },
        "post": {
            "tags": ["Post"],
            "description": "...",
        }
    },

    "/other": {
        "get": {
            "tags": ["Other"],
            "description": "...",
        },
        "post": {
            "tags": ["Other"],
            "description": "...",
        }
    },
}
```

This is not obvious at all on the documentation. Actually the documentation is very complete but lacks an index and some organisation.

Comment: We added a Table of Contents in V3 :-) https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/OpenAPI.next/versions/3.0.md